# getting System.NullReferenceException:

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" getting this error while running migration This is Employee Model Service interface

```
 public interface IEmployeeService : IService<Employee>
      {
          IEnumerable <Employee> GetEmployees(string name = null);
           Employee GetEmployee(string name);
           Employee GetEmployee(int id);
           void CreateEmployee(Employee employee);
           void SaveEmployee();

       }
```

this is Employee Service code

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees(string name)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? UnitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.GetAll() : UnitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.Name == name);
    }
```

this Employee controller where error is occur

```
    public JsonResult GetEmployees()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Employee> employee = _employeeService.GetEmployees().ToList();
            IEnumerable<EmployeeListViewModel> viewModelListEmployee= 
       Mapper.DynamicMap<IEnumerable<Employee>, IEnumerable<EmployeeListViewModel>>(employee);
         return new JsonSuccessResult(viewModelListEmployee);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity;
            return new JsonErrorResult(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Please anybody can elaborate that why i am getting this error from this code??? Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is _employeeService initialized? Try commenting out lines of code to see which line fails

Comment: ...or attach **debugger** to see what is null.

Comment: I tried debugger but could not figure out the problem.

Comment: Try to get the stacktrace to know where exactly (the code line) is throwing the exception.

Comment: What is `ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity`? You'll get `NullReferenceException` if you attempt to cast a null to a non-nullable. I can't see anything else that might cause this, since unless you throw an exception in your catch block, you're swallowing all exceptions.

Comment: Seems that `ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity` is an attempt to return HTTP 422 status code, which is part of `WebException`. Probably it tried to assign HTTP status code to `Response` but at that time `Response` instance is null, throwing NRE.